# Svg viewbox doesn't return correct mouse points with nested svg in Firefox

Tags: svg

I've little problem with Firefox v25 when I try to get mouse position.
FF don't return correct position when I use 2 svg nested, but in Chrome and IE10 work fine.

This is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/LwZFb/

```
<div class="position">
    <div>client position <span id="clientPosition"></span></div>
    <div>svg position <span id="svgPosition"></span></div>
</div>
<svg id="test1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500px" height="500px">
<svg id="testSVG" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="500px" height="500px">
    <rect fill="papayaWhip" x="250" y="250" width="500" height="500"/>
    <text x="225" y="240">250/250</text>
    <text x="725" y="240">750/250</text>
    <text x="225" y="775">250/750</text>
    <text x="725" y="775">750/750</text>
    <rect id="followMe" fill="peachPuff" stroke="crimson" width="20" height="20"/>
</svg>
</svg>
```

and the js code for to get the position:

```
var svgElement = document.getElementById('testSVG'),
followRectElement = document.getElementById('followMe'),
clientPositionElement = document.getElementById('clientPosition'),
svgPositionElement = document.getElementById('svgPosition');

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(mouseEvent) {
    var svgPoint = svgElement.createSVGPoint();

    svgPoint.x = mouseEvent.clientX;
    svgPoint.y = mouseEvent.clientY;

    svgPoint = svgPoint.matrixTransform(svgElement.getScreenCTM().inverse());

    clientPositionElement.innerHTML = [ mouseEvent.clientX, mouseEvent.clientY ].join('/');
    svgPositionElement.innerHTML = [ svgPoint.x, svgPoint.y ].join('/');

    followRectElement.setAttribute('x', svgPoint.x - 10);
    followRectElement.setAttribute('y', svgPoint.y - 10);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh but Firefox does give the right location, the other browsers and your algorithm are the issue. This is the problem line...

```
svgPoint = svgPoint.matrixTransform(svgElement.getScreenCTM().inverse());
```

The svgElement is in a different co-ordinate system to the svgPoint as the svgElement has a viewBox and [viewBox transforms only apply to descendants and not to the element itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) Unfortunately IE and Chrome don't adhere to the SVG specification here which causes much confusion.

Instead of the above line you could write this instead

```
svgPoint = svgPoint.matrixTransform(followRectElement.getScreenCTM().inverse());
```

as the followRectElement is in the co-ordinate system you want, a solution which will work cross browser.